# discord py - error handling with on_command_error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, discord.py

I need help with the error handling in discord.py. I want to send the server owner a private message if my bot doesn't have enough rights for a command or if my bots fail something (reason not enough rights) with the right, that he needs.

Now I searched a lot and can't find a good example that shows this. I know how to send the Owner a private message, but the "isinstance" thing confuses me very hard, I never used it before. But this is an important feature, that I would love to integrate.

Answer (score 4):

Preface: Since you are talking about error handling, I am assuming that the member is trying to use a command, but the bot does not have enough permissions to properly execute the function body of the command.

### Sample Solution

```py
@commands.command(name="kick")
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, members, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)

@kick.error
async def kick_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        owner = ctx.guild.owner
        direct_message = await owner.create_dm()
        await direct_message.send("Missing Permissions")
```

### Details

The [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function is a Python built-in function which takes two arguments, `object` and `classinfo`. The function returns whether or not the `object` argument is an instance of `classinfo`. In this case, the error caused by the bot not having enough permissions raises a `discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions` error.

The `isinstance()` function in this case checks if the exception raised is an instance of `commands.MissingPermissions`. If the exception is the `discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions` error, then `isinstance()` will return `True`.

The code of the `if` clause is easier to understand. The owner of the guild (as a `discord.Member` object) is stored as an attribute of `discord.Guild` objects; in this case, [`ctx.guild.owner`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.owner). Since the object is a `discord.Member` object, the [`create_dm()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.create_dm) classmethod can be called to create a private direct message channel. In that channel, the message is sent.

Comment: How can i send the owner the permission that the bot needs? Because i want to use that for every command.

Comment: Since `kick_error` is raised when the bot does not have the **Kick Members** permission (`kick_members`), then you could simply add that to the string which is sent. This could be done everywhere necessary.